# Changing color of buttons when wrong/right answer is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, button, background-color

I have four buttons in a specific part of the experiment, this is the HTML code.

```
<div id="test" style="display:none">
        <div class="row center-block text-center">
            <img id="testImage" src="static/img/errorhedgehog.jpg" height="300">
        </div>
        <div class="row text-center center-block">
            <h3 id="labelPrompt">Choose the corresponding label:</h3>
        </div>
         <div class="row text-center center-block">
            <button class="quizChoice btn btn-md btn-info" id="quizChoice0"></button>
        </div>
         <div class="row text-center center-block">
            <button class="quizChoice btn btn-md btn-info" id="quizChoice1"></button>
        </div>
         <div class="row text-center center-block">
            <button class="quizChoice btn btn-md btn-info" id="quizChoice2"></button>
        </div>
         <div class="row text-center center-block">
            <button class="quizChoice btn btn-md btn-info" id="quizChoice3"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="row text-center">
            <p>Press enter or click 'Next' to go to the next item.</p>
            <button id="nextTest" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Next</button>
        </div>
        <div class="progress">
            <div id="testProgress" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%;" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Four different answers appear on the buttons. The correct one is defined in the script and the other three appear on the other buttons.

```
var rightLabel = partTest[trial].label
var choiceLabels = ["hola", "hole", "holo", rightLabel];
        $("choiceLabels").css("background-color", "transparent");
        for (var i=0; i<choiceLabels.length; i++) {
            var theID="#quizChoice"+i.toString();
            $(theID).text(choiceLabels[i])
```

I'm trying to change the color of buttons so that when the right answer is clicked, the background color of this button turns green. Similarly, when the wrong answer is clicked, the background color of this button turns red and the right one turns green.

```
$(".quizChoice").click(function() {
        var theChoice=$(this).text();
        if (theChoice===rightLabel) {
            alert("Good job!")
            $("#rightLabel").css("background-color", "green");
        } else {
            alert("Too bad! The correct label is " + rightLabel);
            $("#theChoice").css("background-color", "red");
            $("#rightLabel").css("background-color", "green");
        }
    });
```

But nothing changes at all?

Comment: Which alert do you get?

Comment: The alert appears (either "Good job!" or "Too bad!") depending on which button I click, but the colors don't change.

Comment: i did copy your code into code pen and nothing is working

Comment: It's a part of an entire experiment with different training and testing rounds but I just copied the part that I thought was most relevant.

Comment: I don't see `#theChoice` and `#rightLabel` in the HTML. Where are they?

Comment: Ah, that's because I did not add them to the HTML file. Is that the problem?

Comment: Yes, if there's no `div` with ID "theChoice", how can you change its color?

Comment: ^ You are saying change the colour of the element with the id of "theChoice" but it does not exist. "#theChoice" should be more like "#"+theChoice

Answer (score 1):

You're putting the `rightLabel` and `theChoice` variable name as part of the string in the jQuery selector instead of referencing the value. Try something like this based on your example:

```js
var rightLabel = 'B';

$(".quizChoice").click(function() {
  var theChoice = $(this).text();

  if (theChoice === rightLabel) {
    alert("Good job!")
    $("#" + theChoice).css("background-color", "green");
  } else {
    alert("Too bad! The correct label is " + rightLabel);
    $("#" + theChoice).css("background-color", "red");
    $("#" + rightLabel).css("background-color", "green");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quizChoice" id="A">A</div>
<div class="quizChoice" id="B">B</div>
```

Comment: $(`#${theChoice}`) could be `$('#'+theChoice)` yes?

Comment: @CraigvanTonder, no, these are string templates. note the backticks. It's a bit ES6-y but it works just fine.

Comment: It could be - it wouldn't make a difference to the execution. I just prefer to use template literals. However it's not good to use two styles so I've updated the answer to match the question style

Comment: Sure I understand that, just think it's simplier to understand when you're concatenating the variable onto a string. Maybe for larger strings template literals would make more sense :)